# Dotnet build "Access to the path is denied"; windows container docker build on Teamcity agent

Tags: .net, docker, teamcity, docker-build

I was having trouble building a locally working image on a Teamcity agent, when generating doc files, I got the error `Access to the path 'C:\src\xxx' is denied`.

Unfortunately most answers are for Linux containers and suggestions didn't work.

Adding `USER "NT Authority\System"` to the docker file solved the issue. If there's any other suggestions, fire away.

Comment: Could you further elaborate what build job is attempting to use c:\src, ideally all work within docker containers will need to be performed within secure paths.

Comment: It was the generation of the documentation files for swashbuckle during build.

Comment: Could you let me know which binary is running for code generation? There will be a flag for setting the correct directory. To which you want to run this within the teamcity work directory for your build.

Answer (score -1):

Adding USER `NT Authority\System` to the docker file solved the issue.

Comment: By security principles, docker agents do not run with any elevation. Whilst elevating to User System will get around this problem. It will open it to a security issue within your stack.